# How to open Chrome specific profile from spotlight on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Is it possible to launch Chrome with specific profile from Spotlight on macOS Big Sur?

I found answers (old) that [this is possible with a command](https://superuser.com/questions/759535/open-google-chrome-specific-profile-from-command-line-mac).

Comment: "a command" … what command. Please show us your research so we don't have to do it all again.

Comment: For instance: https://superuser.com/questions/759535/open-google-chrome-specific-profile-from-command-line-mac

Answer (score 1):

You could set that up with a simple bash script using the command you linked to and setting up a soft link.

Replace "PROFILE_NAME" with whatever you want.

1. Create script: `sudo nano ~/PROFILE_NAME`
2. Fill it with this text

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory=PROFILE_NAME
   ```
3. Make executable: `chmod +x ~/PROFILE_NAME`
4. Create link: `ln -s ~/PROFILE_NAME /usr/local/bin/PROFILE_NAME`
5. Type PROFILE_NAME into spotlight.