# Create Chrome shortcut that opens a specific user profile in Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, shortcuts

I've seen tutorials on how to do this on other operating systems, but I can't for the life of me make it work on Windows 10.

Comment: [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start Chrome using a specified "user profile"?](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on my Win 10 PC.

The file path to the `chrome.exe` is different on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

So for mine the file path to the exe was:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Then add the switch:

```
-profile-directory="Profile 2"
```

Or whatever `Profile` you want to access.

So the final path for the shortcut should look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -profile-directory="Profile 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a shortcut of Chrome executable and append the `--profile-directory` to it.

Please advice this tutorial on how to do so:
https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags