# Google Chrome - setting a default starting user

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-accounts

I have three Google accounts:

- Personal account
- Work account
- External account (a client's apps, where the client has given me a login)

On my work computer, I always want the browser to start up using my "Work" account when I open Chrome (no matter whether via clicking a link, opening a shortcut or otherwise).

At the moment, it opens using the most recent profile used.

How can I achieve this?  I am using Windows 7 Pro and Google Chrome 52.0 (64-bit).  I don't want to have to rely on double-clicking a specific desktop shortcut to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can specify a particular profile you want to use, by using a launch argument, on a desktop shortcut.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start Chrome using a specified "user profile"?](http://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile)

Comment: I was about to answer when I found the dupe :)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill - that linked question appears to be about starting Chrome with a specific profile from command line/desktop shortcut only (unless I misread it)... I was hoping to set a default user such that Chrome always opened using the default user (no matter if the user clicks a desktop shorcut, a link in email or a website link, for example).

Comment: So you want to be logged on to three accounts at work?

Comment: Hi @techraf  - Yes, I want to be able to access all three accounts at work.  I primarily use my 'Work' account at work (so I always want Chrome to start with 'Work' profile.  Sometimes I'll want to grab something off my 'Personal' profile (holiday bookings, for example) and I'll want to temporarily switch.  I also have clients who demand that I use a profile they create on their Google Apps account (as a part of a larger multi-company team), so I'll need to be able to switch to that profile temporarily as well when I'm working on that project.