# Chrome Profile to Directory mapping

Tags: google-chrome

I can browse to `C:\Users\<my-user>\appdata\local\google\chrome\User Data` and among other directories there are Chrome's user profiles in directories like `Profile 1`, `Profile 2` etc.

However, in Chrome's UI, the profiles have their own names (set by me when I made them), but no reference to the profile directory that they map to.

How can I map the name of a Chrome profile to the Directory it is stored in?

Comment: Where are you encountering such a need?

Comment: Profile directory is needed to start chrome under a specific profile https://superuser.com/a/377195/54993

Answer (score 7):

Profile Path is visible by browsing to `chrome://version` on a given profile:

Example:

```
Google Chrome   90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (x86_64)
Revision    4df112c29cfe9a2c69b14195c0275faed4e997a7-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#1348}
OS  macOS Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G8022)
JavaScript  V8 9.0.257.23
User agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation
Executable Path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Profile Path    /Users/staffordwilliams/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```