# How to have three different browsers with different site blacklist or whitelist?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, chromium, waterfox

Let's say I want to have three browsers which have different blacklist or whitelist.

For example,

Browser1.exe blocks facebook.com only (blacklist)
Browser2.exe allows gmail.com only (whitelist)
Browser3.exe allows url with "google" only (whitelist)

This is just an example. No need to do the exact same thing.

How can I do this?

Maybe, is it possible to have three separate exe programs of Chrome or Chromium? Then I can install parental management or other blacklist/whitelist Chrome extension plugins on all of those programs, but use different blacklist and whitelist for each of them.

Similarly, maybe, is it possible to have three separate exe programs of Firefox or Waterfox?  Then I can install parental management or other blacklist/whitelist Firefox plugins on all of those programs, but use different blacklist and whitelist for each of them.

Or, maybe you have any other idea that might work? Any suggestion that might work will be appreciated.

Comment: Use three different browsers? Say Chrome, Firefox and [Ungoogled Chromium](https://chromium.woolyss.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Create in your browser three profiles, each with its own separate
blacklist/whitelist lists (actually separate everything).

You may create desktop icons which will run the browser with each
profile.

For example, for Chrome you may add a parameter to the invocation like
`--profile-directory="Profile 1"`.

Comment: How do I do "create in your browser three profiles"? What does "profile" mean here? And where do I add a "parameter"? What does "parameter" mean in your last sentence?

Comment: "parameter" is also called "argument" or "switch" and is added on the command-line that launches the browser. For example, see for Chrome [Share Chrome with others](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). For Windows I would call Chrome for Profile1 with the command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1`.

Comment: I tried this. It seems I can just open any profile name. That is, even if I don't create a new profile named "random not exist", I can open a chrome browser by typing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="random not exist" in the command prompt.

Comment: It may ignore invalid arguments. See [How do I start Chrome using a specified "user profile"?](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile)