# Transfer Google Chrome profiles from Ubuntu to windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, google-chrome

I have to use both Ubuntu and Windows. Consequently I also need to use Google Chrome on both. I have tried to transfer my chrome profiles FROM Ubuntu 20.04 to Windows 10 unsuccessfully despite scrutinizing the different guidance found on here, blogs and Google chrome support.

*(Note: I have read several threads on transferring profiles from windows to another windows pc, or windows to linux. This is different, I want to transfer from Ubuntu to Windows)*

So far, here is what I have done:

1. Copy the chrome profiles located in : `~/.config/google-chrome`
   from Ubuntu to a pen drive,
2. Delete  profiles in
   `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` on the
   drive of the windows target pc,
3. Finally copy from pen drive to
   `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`.

When opening Chrome from the target Windows 10 PC, **the expected profiles do not show up**.
What I would expect is the following chrome profiles menu showing up when launching Google Chrome:
[Chrome Profiles Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJw3o.png)

In other words, the 3 steps described above do not work. I wonder if transferring chrome profiles from Ubuntu to windows is even possible.

Please note that some of the chrome profiles are linked to NO google account, so the google sync is not an option. In fact I want to keep the chrome settings (such as the name of the chrome window and other chrome settings like pinned tabs)

Is there a way to achieve a successful transfer of chrome profiles FROM ubuntu TO windows?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there may be multiple Chrome profiles. After transferring the profile from Ubuntu, it must be selected. This can be done by a [command line argument](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile), or [by selecting the default profile in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

However, there *might* be issues transferring a profile between Linux and Windows because of [differing end-of-line conventions](https://www.commandlinewizardry.com/post/removing-windows-line-breaks). Windows uses CHR(13)+CHR(10) (\r\n) to terminate a line, Linux just CHR(10) (\n). In copying a Firefox profile, a few years ago, I found a file or two needed editing to accommodate that difference, which might no longer be an issue; I've not tried it with Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried the command line suggestion and it actually seems to work, at least partially as I do find the pinned tabs  but not all settings though. The "Selecting profile in Chrome" part refers to sync profiles which is different to what I am looking for; indeed this seems to not retrieve the setttings I want. Overall, the command line trick makes my profiles showing up in the profiles menu of chrome. Many thanks

Comment: This works to show up a profile in the menu: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"

Comment: @Jerome, Glad it worked at least partially. As mentioned, I found that a file or two in the *Firefox* profile needed editing when transferred between Linux and Windows because of line termination characters. That could explain loss of *some* settings. Some settings you can export and then import, e.g., site passwords: https://support.nordpass.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002451798-How-to-export-passwords-from-Google-Chrome-